# How to choose an object relational mapping for .net

Tags: .net, orm

(This must be a FAQ, so I expect it to be closed as duplicate, however I can not find a question that contains a good **overview** of the **issues** etc.)

**What** should someone consider when **choosing** an ORM for a **.net** system?

**How** are the above **addressed** by the ORM that are in common usage for .net systems.

(Witch stack overflow question should I link to in an answers when I says “consider using a ORM” for a .net question)

**Does on one wish to provide a new answer and get the bounty?**

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectRelationalToolComparisonDotNet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the main question/answer I have been pointing people at in regards to choosing a .NET ORM:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)

I put a bunch of the "duplicate" type questions in my answer on that one.  So there is plenty of reading you can do from a variety of different perspectives.

I'll also try to answer your specific questions:

> What should someone consider when
>   choosing an ORM for a .net system?

- You want to make sure it works with
  your database.  If your database
  design was state of the art 15 years
  ago, many of the smaller and/or less mature
  ORMs won't work with your lack of
  keys, weird relationships, etc.
- You want to make sure it works with
  your database vendor.  SQL Server
  support is pretty much always
  available, but other databases may or
  may not be supported by various ORMs
  (MYSQL seems to be the second most
  commonly supported database).
- If you want to generate your database
  based on your .NET classes, you need
  to make sure your ORM supports that.
- If you want performance, I guess you
  stay away from the bad performing
  ones, but those would never make a
  top 5 list, so as long as you go with
  an ORM that has some mainstream
  street cred, you are probably fine
  here.
- You need to make sure it has features you need supported: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/12/25ReasonsNotToWriteYourOwnObjectRelationalMapper.aspx
- Consider vendor lock-in and how
  easily you may or may not be able to
  escape it (for both the database
  vendor and the ORM vendor).
- Consider how much you want to spend.
- Consider what you want for code
  generation.
- Consider what you want for unit test
  support.
- Consider how much time you want to
  spend researching the various
  options.
- Consider the community that exists
  around the ORM.

There are plenty of things to keep in mind.  I'm sure I could think of more.  In the end, a lot of it is situational and you need to make your own decision what is best for you and your project.

> How are the above addressed by the ORM
>   that are in common usage for .net
>   systems.

The only .NET ORM that I am aware of that meets pretty much all needs a .NET project could have (minus the more obscure database vendors) is NHibernate.  It has been tested with a lot of "legacy" databases in a lot of different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

[ORM Battle](http://ormbattle.net/)
A entire website dedicated to analysing and comparing various .NET ORM (Object Relational Mapping) products!

Bear in mind, though, that even the ORMBattle website only compares about 7 or 8 ORM's (although the ones it does compare, it seems to do so fairly thoroughly but see disclaimer below).

According to the [SharpToolBox website](http://sharptoolbox.com), there are about 40 ORM's available!
The list of ORM products, and their descriptions on the SharpToolBox website should give you a good start.  See here:
[SharpToolBox Search Results for Object-Relational Mapping](http://sharptoolbox.com/search?ToolName%253d%2526Category%253d74089b0a-1105-4389-b1db-eedf27e20cfb%2526Attribute%253d-800)

Considering that pretty much every developer, and every application's data access needs can vary, finding a complete comparison between all of them will be difficult.  This is probably the reason that over 40 different ORM products exist since there is no "one-size-fits-all" in the world of ORM.

Also, please bear in mind that any comparisons between ORM products may well be "flawed" since you can't always be sure that the various functionality of different ORM products is designed for the exact same purposes.  A comment by AJ on this answer links to a [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/15/benchmarks-are-useless-yes-again.aspx) by [Ayende Rahien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366/ayende-rahien) who describes exactly this phenomenon when ORMBattle compared NHibernate to other ORMs.

I think the best approach is to look at the benchmarks, and read the descriptions of each ORM, but don't take those things literally, but rather interpret those figures based upon what your own application should be doing.  For example, if your application primarily reads and writes database records one at a time, you'll probably use a completely different ORM product than an application that needs to process database records in batches.

Comment: The usefulness of the analysis done by ORM Battle is highly contested... a good read: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/15/benchmarks-are-useless-yes-again.aspx

Comment: @AJ - Interesting article.  I do agree that benchmarks (of anything) can be misleading.  This is why each person looking for an ORM tool should do their own research due to everyone (and their needs) being different.  Benchmarks can often be like statistics, and we know how useful they can be!  ;)   (http://www.quotegarden.com/statistics.html)

Comment: That's why there is big FAQ section :) See http://ormbattle.net/index.php/faqs.html

Comment: I can add why there are JUST 8 products now: few commercial vendors simply asked us to remove their results. I think that's not really funny at all - see e.g. http://ormbattle.net/index.php/blog/93-great-quote-from-todays-e-mail.html

Comment: We'd add other tools, if they support LINQ, but it seems there are no more such candidates. And finally, we invite everyone (with or without LINQ support) - test suite is fully open source.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a .net developer, but you should check out [nHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html). It is the .net version of the state of the art ORM for Java. I am sure it is a great solution for .net too, as ist makes mapping objects quite easy, but is still powerfull enough to map objects to nearly any kind of sql schema.

Answer (score 0):

Choose between NHibernate or Entity Framework. NHibernate is more extensible and generally more feature rich. Entity Framework works better and easy to use with rich feature set.

Both frameworks are great, Entity Framework has one big advantage over NHibernate: it is far easier to get working, the startup phase can be quite hard. EF does this far better. However, in some areas NHibernate is superior, e.g. when it comes to extending the framework NHibernate offers more options

At last, take your call. Either of two will never disappoint you for sure.